# Binomial integral methods

Tags: binomial-theorem

If $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ has the integral part $I$ and the decimated part $f$ then prove that

$(I+f) (I-f) =1$

I did the following

$(2+\sqrt{3})^n=I+f$

$(2-\sqrt{3})^n=f'$

Thus adding both

We get

$(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n=I+f+f'$

Since the left part is integer by

binomial expansion therefore

$f+f'=1 $- - - - - - - eqn A

If we multiply $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ and

$(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ then we get $1$

Hence $(I+f) (f') =1$

Thus we get from eqn A we get

$(I+f) (1-f)=1$

But we have to prove that $(I+f) (I-f) =1$

How to do so? Is the question

wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: Try using LaTeX. This website might be helpful : http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php

Comment: The question is wrong, you are right (for $n\geq1$).  For sure $(I+f)(I-f) \geq 3^n(3^n-1) >1$.

Comment: To answer your comment on my now deleted answer..the integral part for both plus and minus variant are identical no? So you can expand the second one as $I +f'$?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Because the integral part arises when you have even powers of the expansion with respect to $\sqrt{3}$ so that the sign on the sqrt is removed. No?